# Edit link_to behind user and nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to construct a link for a object that's nested behind a user and shopmain routes: user>shompmain>shopaddress

I can't get the show/edit/delete links working.

```
<%= link_to 'Show', user_shopmain_shopaddress_path(shopaddress.shopmain, shopaddress), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_shopmain_shopaddress_path(shopaddress.shopmain, shopaddress), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', user_shopmain_shopaddress_path(shopaddress.shopmain, shopaddress), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-danger btn-sm" %>
```

I get this error that reads something like. It seems like I'm missing the id for the shopaddress for some reason.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"shop/shopaddresses", :id=>nil, :shopmain_id=>#<Shop::Shopaddress id: 2, shopadrsline1: "Civic Place", shopadrsline2: "Box 888", shopadrscity: "Toronto", shopadrsprovince: "ON", shopadrspostalcode: "N0N1V0", shopmain_id: 2, created_at: "2016-01-17 03:38:47", updated_at: "2016-01-17 03:38:47">, :user_id=>#<Shop::Shopmain id: 2, shopname: "Eastwood", shoptagline: "Testing", user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-01-17 03:30:01", updated_at: "2016-01-17 03:30:01">} missing required keys: [:id]
```

My routes file readslike

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    # Devise Authetication
    devise_for :users
    devise_for :admins

    # Website Pages
    root 'website/page#index'

    # Backend Shop Module
    resources :users do
        scope module: "shop" do
            resources :shopmains do
                resources :shopdetails
                resources :shopaddresses
                resources :shophours
            end
        end
    end

end
```

My shopaddresses controller looks like:

```
class Shop::ShopaddressesController < ApplicationController

    # Security and Layouts
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    layout 'layouts/shop/application.html.erb'
    before_action :set_shopaddress, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # Shop Address Index
    def index
        shopmain = Shop::Shopmain.find(params[:shopmain_id])
        @shopaddresses = shopmain.shopaddresses
    end

    # Shop Address Single View
    def show
        shopmain = Shop::Shopmain.find(params[:shopmain_id])
        @shopmain = shopmain.shopaddresses.find(params[:id])
    end

    # New Shop Address
    def new
        shopmain = Shop::Shopmain.find(params[:shopmain_id])
        @shopaddress = shopmain.shopaddresses.build
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # new.html.erb
            format.xml  { render :xml => @shopmain }
        end
    end

    # Edit Shop Address
    def edit
        shopmain = Shop::Shopmain.find(params[:shopmain_id])
        @shopaddress = shopmain.shopaddresses.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Create a New Shop Address
    def create
        @shopmain = Shop::Shopmain.find(params[:shopmain_id])
        @shopaddress = @shopmain.shopaddresses.create(shopaddress_params)
        respond_to do |format|
        if @shopaddress.save
            format.html { redirect_to user_shopmain_shopaddresses_path, notice: 'Comment for Shopmain was Successfully Created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @shopaddress }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @shopaddress.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # Update Shop Address
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
        if @shopaddress.update(shopaddress_params)
            format.html { redirect_to user_shopmain_shopaddresses_path, notice: 'Comment for Shopmain was Successfully Updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'edit' }
                format.json { render json: @shopaddress.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # Delete Shop Address
    def destroy
        @shopmain = Shop::Shopmain.find(params[:shopmain_id])
        @shopaddress = @shopmain.shopaddresses.find(params[:id])
        @shopaddress.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to user_shopmain_shopaddresses_path, notice: 'Comment for Shopmain was Successfully Deleted.'  }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end

    private

    # Common Constrainsts
    def set_shopaddress
        @shopaddress = Shop::Shopaddress.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Strong Params Whitelist
    def shopaddress_params
        params.require(:shop_shopaddress).permit(:shopadrsline1, :shopadrsline2, :shopadrscity, :shopadrsprovince, :shopadrspostalcode, :shopmain_id)
    end

end
```

The full index view (per comments request)

```
<!-- Information Card -->
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Shop Listing Index</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Address Line 1</th>
                        <th>Address Line 2</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Province</th>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <% @shopaddresses.each do |shopaddress| %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= shopaddress.shopadrsline1 %></td>
                            <td><%= shopaddress.shopadrsline2 %></td>
                            <td><%= shopaddress.shopadrscity %></td>
                            <td><%= shopaddress.shopadrsprovince %></td>
                            <td><%= shopaddress.shopadrspostalcode %></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Member Contact Group">
                                    <%= link_to 'Show', user_shopmain_shopaddress_path(shopaddress.shopmain, shopaddress), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
                                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_shopmain_shopaddress_path(shopaddress.shopmain, shopaddress), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
                                    <%= link_to 'Delete', user_shopmain_shopaddress_path(shopaddress.shopmain, shopaddress), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-danger btn-sm" %>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <% end %>
                </tbody>

            </table>

            <%= link_to 'New Address', new_user_shopmain_shopaddress_path, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Van you update the question with the full code of the view page?

Comment: Thanks Pavan. Inserted the full view at bottom.

Comment: I just realized some code was missing and just fixed it.

Comment: Where is the variable (or method) `shopaddresses` (not `@shopaddresses`) defined? It is used in the view several times. Please also note that the `link_to` code that you cite in the question is different from that in the code block (`shopaddresses` versus `shopaddress`). Please correct.

Comment: Hello Tilmo. Sorry trying to work through the problem and pasted a bad view. Updated everything just now. 

The reason why I put variable shopaddresses b/c the variable shopaddress on the form caused an error. When changed from singular to plural the form worked all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you said your show link works as it clearly cannot work. :) Your route helpers expect three parameters, not two - you are missing user id. So it should be:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', user_shopmain_shopaddresses_path(current_user, shopaddress.shopmain, shopaddress), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
```

Comment: Thanks my bad I should've updated my question when show link started to fail. Surprisingly just by changing the route to plural (among other things) made the show link work, but the others never did. 

But anyways thanks for your answer this helped and worked :)